# SAXS: Why would a second order peak behave differently than first order?

Tags: x-rays, nanoscience, x-ray-crystallography

What is the significance of a second order peak in SAXS and during an assembly of nanoparticles, why would it have a different shape over time:
[image: 1st order peak behavior]

[image: 2nd order peak behavior]

What are factors that are unique to first or second order diffraction signal intensity?

Answer (score 1):

The terminology "first" and "second" order implies the use of an [expansion in series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html) to model the data. The use in physics is for series that converge.  Example:

$1/{(1-x)}= 1 + x +x^2 ...$

Each term  is  called an order, $1$ is zeroth order $x$ is first order $x^2$ is second etc.In fitting data in physics, each term  usually has in front a coupling constant, smaller than 1, which gets the power of the given order. Thus the second order is smaller by the square of the coupling constant, which is what you observe in the figure you give. A drastic diminution in the y axis numbers for second order.

The functional form of a second order in an expansion in series is different than that of first order, as the example shows, and it will depend on the specific original function that is expanded into the series.